# What is the best way to create an info panel with text aligned to left

Tags: pine-script

Here is an example of an info panel that I would like to recreate.
I tried with a label with `style=label.style_labelup`. I also tried with a table, it looks very nice, however it's not scrollable and the content is being cut.

Besides the Text alignment to the left, I am also interested on the red and green circles, not sure if it's just emojis or unicode circles coloured.

[Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pUOS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to use tables for this purpose. If it is being cut you can try using smaller text size eg `table.cell(text_size = size.small)` and/or format into multiple columns. The red/green circles are just unicode characters.

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_table{dot}cell](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_table%7Bdot%7Dcell)

https://unicode-table.com/en/1F7E2/

https://unicode-table.com/en/1F534/

Comment: Thank you @rumpypumpydumpy for your answer. I already tried the text size, it's still cutting it. I also thought of the columns, however it would take too much screen size. The solution there is simple, display only some of the sections at the time, not all at once. 
I do like tables a lot, if it was scrollable I would definitely be happy with that result. However I see this example I posted on screenshot managed to achieve it without them, I would like to replicate that given the options I have.

Comment: About the red circle, yes I tried them already, however on the green circle I cannot display it, shows the square with question mark. not sure why, if its a local issue.

Comment: Another limitation with the tables that I'm doing it on a Strategy, and to be able to use `if barstate.islast` I need to have `calc_on_every_tick = true`, which as of now with my current knowledge is not the way I would go about it, since my strategy uses higher timeframe securities to determine entries.

Comment: It's not clear why you're still having issues. You can easily display many more lines of text than your example with size.small and size.tiny. The green unicode character should render fine unless you're maybe using some bizarre non standard browser or system font, and barstate.islast only needs to be used for the portion of the code that renders the table. You could always try using barstate.isconfirmed instead if it's an issue. It's purely to prevent the table being redrawn every bar update/tick unnecessarily which can cause your script to timeout. https://www.tradingview.com/x/rNgkIqW2/

Comment: Thank you very much Rumpy. Regarding the unicode, I was using that same site, running MacOS, on any browser. Also I use the TradingView App instead of browser. 
About the `barstate.islast` I see it's the recommended way to use on the documentation, but for it to work on a strategy I need `calc_on_every_tick = true` and that would mess with the strategy itself. I could try with `barstate.isconfirmed`